# Crystal Report issue.Net 4.0

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

There is a definite syntax of passing value to crystal-report Formula Field from .Net 4.0-  Code 
behind

E.g. (C# Code):

Following will NOT work

```
_rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fClient"].Text = Mr.Gates;
```

Following will work-

```
_rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fClient"].Text = "\"Mr.Gates\"";
```

I haven't understand the prominence and way of using following ..

```
"\" \""
```

What if "Mr. Gates:" is in some variable, I want to pass!?
plz reply with some code...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

\" sends a literal " through to the variable. For literal string values in Formulae to be seen as literal strings they must be quoted hence sending the quoted " through is necessary.